# Returning values from Thread in Batches

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, asynchronous

I am spawning a Thread to query the DB. The intention is to have this done asynchronously. Now every Query returns me a lot of rows. What i want is that my thread keeps making a batch of say 5 and return back the set of values to the UI Thread which would keep displaying it. Is there some way to be able to achieve this?
I am using Java with Spring for my platform

Answer (score 1):

Let the thread which queries DB read 5 items, pack them in an object whose class implements Runnable, and pass that object to UI by `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.